# TikZ edge between multiple source nodes and single target node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to achieve something like the following:

[image: Sample image]

(Please ignore the node styles, I've sorted that part, it's the edges I'm struggling with!)

My diagrams can have undirected edges that join arbitrary sets of nodes together; I use small perpendicular marks to distinguish different edges. So for example, the rightmost edge above is a single edge with two source nodes and a single target, and the two edges to its left are distinct.

My questions are:

1. How can I easily add the perpendicular marks (I'd ideally like to say "add a small mark after 70% of the edge")?
2. How do I specify an edge with multiple source nodes (or multiple target nodes)? I suppose I'd like to specify a point "someway" between the connection points as the "convergence" point of the edges.

I realise number 2 is quite vague, since I haven't specified precisely what I want, but I hope someone can point me in the right direction!

My (very) poor attempt so far is as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, circle] (p0)                     {};
    \node[draw, circle] (p1) [right of=p0]       {};
    \node[draw, circle] (p2) [above right of=p1] {};
    \node[draw, circle] (p3) [below right of=p1] {};
    \node[draw, circle] (p4) [below right of=p2] {};
    \draw (p0.east) to (p1.west);
    \draw (p1.east) to (p2.west);
    \draw (p1.east) to (p3.west);
    \draw (p2.east) -- (p3.east) -- (p4.west); % This is just wrong! :-)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Remarks

Concerning your questions

1. You can use the `mark inside` property on your path, where the first argument is the segment of the path where the mark will be placed, e.g. `\draw[mark inside=0.7] (0,0) -- (1,1);` will set the mark at 70% of the line.
2. I introduced an additional node in between the three ones called `(helper)`.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{petri,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
    >=latex,
    node distance = 2cm,
    every place/.style = {minimum size = 6mm},
    mark inside/.style = {
        postaction = {
            decorate,
            decoration={
                markings,
                mark=at position #1 with {\draw[-] (0,-0.1) -- (0,0.1);}
            }
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Places
    \node[place,tokens=1] (p0)                                           {};
    \node[coordinate]     (start)  [node distance=0.5cm,left of=p0]      {};
    \node[place,tokens=1] (p1)     [right of=p0]                         {};
    \node[place]          (p2)     [above right of=p1]                   {};
    \node[place]          (p3)     [below right of=p1]                   {};
    \node[coordinate]     (helper) [below right of=p2]                   {};
    \node[place]          (p4)     [node distance=0.7cm,right of=helper] {};
    \node[coordinate]     (end)    [node distance=0.5cm,right of=p4]     {};
    % Connections
    \draw (start)   edge[->]                               (p0.west);
    \draw (p0.east) edge[>->]                              (p1.west);
    \draw (p1.east) edge[>->,mark inside=0.5,out=0,in=180] (p2.west);
    \draw (p1.east) edge[>->,mark inside=0.5,out=0,in=180] (p3.west);
    \draw (p2.east) edge[>-,out=0,in=180]                  (helper);
    \draw (p3.east) edge[>-,out=0,in=180]                  (helper);
    \draw (helper)  edge[mark inside=0,->]                 (p4.west);
    \draw (p4.east) edge[>-]                               (end);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: Instead of drawing the bar you can also use the `\arrow{|}`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you. There is always an easier way in TikZ `:-)`

Comment: Fantastic, this is just what I was looking for, thanks!